# Visual Studio 2010 gtest plugin error "the system cannot find the file specified" with x64 platform

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, plugins, googletest

I recently moved to a new machine (Win7 - 64 bit), and installed the GTest plugin in Visual Studio 2010.  If I try to use any of the plugin options, for example, "Execute All Tests with GoogleTest", I get an error  "the system cannot find the file specified".  (The project runs fine if I press the Visual Studio run button.)

I'm guessing this is because my Debug configuration is set to Platform=x64, and the output from the build is going into *x64\Debug* directory instead of the *Debug* directory. (When I used to run this on my 32 bit machine, I never ran into this problem with either Debug or Release configuration).

If this is the problem, it I suppose I could change the configuration to output the files into Debug, but that seems klugey.  Any advice on how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I confirmed that changing the output directory to the configuration name fixed the error.  So the only question left is whether there is a better way to configure the GTEST plugin to run the EXE from whatever output directory is specified in the configuration.